# Where is the `cloudicon` font library?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

There is a bootstrap front-end project with a named `cloudicon` font:

[image]

Part code of `cloudicon.css`:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Cloudicon';
  src:  url('../../fonts/cloudicon/Cloudicon.eot?h7rmut');
  src:  url('../../fonts/cloudicon/Cloudicon.eot?h7rmut#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../../fonts/cloudicon/Cloudicon.ttf?h7rmut') format('truetype'),
    url('../../fonts/cloudicon/Cloudicon.woff?h7rmut') format('woff'),
    url('../../fonts/cloudicon/Cloudicon.svg?h7rmut#Cloudicon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
[Cloudicon]:before {
  font-family: 'Cloudicon';
  content: attr(Cloudicon);
  speak: none;
}

[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
  /* use !important to prevent issues with browser extensions that change fonts */
  font-family: 'Cloudicon' !important;
  color: #808080;
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;

  /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
...
```

But I searched all the Google, do not find a font named `cloudicon` lib site. So, who can tell me what is this?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud icon is a Bootstrap font. It's actually using SVG as font icon internally.

You can use it by placing class `glyphicon glyphicon-cloud`.

All Bootstrap [font here](https://www.bootstrapicons.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can find a "Cloudicon" icons library on [graphicriver](https://graphicriver.net/item/cloudicon-300-simple-line-icons/21186263) website